# sequelize table is not associated to user

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use Node.js for Api server and sequelize(version 4) to communicate with MySQL.

Final goal is implement follow&following system.
(It is already implemented and Now I struggle with view user information with associated followers)

[model.js]

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export const sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'id', 'pw', {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
    },
    userid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    userpw: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true
})

User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'follower', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'follower_id'});
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'following', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'following_id'});

sequelize.sync({
    force: false
}, () => console.log("[*] DB Sync complete"));
```

In above code, I defined

`User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'follower', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'follower_id'});
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'following', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'following_id'});`

association to connect with foreign key.

Also router is here.

[router.js]

```
import { User, sequelize } from '../model';
export const getUser = (req, res) => {
    User.find({
        where: {
            userid: req.params.id
        },
        include: [
            {model: sequelize.model("follow")}
        ]
    })
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({status: true, result: result})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({status: false, result: "getUser error"})
    })
}
```

I want to view user information with follower, So I defined `include: [ {model: sequelize.model("follow")} ]`

But when I access to /user/test, it throw error like this -> `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: follow is not associated to user!`

I already defined about relationship. Why this error occured?

[Current result]

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": {
    "no": 1,
    "userid": "girim",
    "userpw": "$2a$10$LnN1UmtKM//8qkze6j6CkuoISl6jh63HUURbmbH6xFVTL3GVWDux.",
    "created_at": "2018-07-19T01:39:43.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-19T01:39:43.000Z"
  }
}
```

[Desired result]

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": {
    "no": 1,
    "userid": "girim",
    "userpw": "$2a$10$LnN1UmtKM//8qkze6j6CkuoISl6jh63HUURbmbH6xFVTL3GVWDux.",
    "created_at": "2018-07-19T01:39:43.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-19T01:39:43.000Z",
    "followers": [
     // follower list here!
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

---

After editing code,

```
    include: [
        { model: User, as: 'follower'}
    ]
```

it works fine. output is here. (I alread insert user `hide` and `test`. And also

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": {
    "no": 3,
    "userid": "hide",
    "userpw": "$2a$10$oN/.mEuSb8RzRkK.NdyNP.ZbkvcWOSMSsMnxmR.jRWB6wodFTyI02",
    "created_at": "2018-07-19T06:01:17.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-19T06:01:17.000Z",
    "follower": [
      {
        "no": 1,
        "userid": "test",
        "userpw": "$2a$10$dVdZ80LYBX9hPsCCfwLC8uhqZD1oWXKyzzIb59m/TOwWr.A5r4rT.",
        "created_at": "2018-07-19T06:00:57.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-07-19T06:00:57.000Z",
        "follow": {
          "created_at": "2018-07-19T06:02:09.000Z",
          "updated_at": "2018-07-19T06:02:09.000Z",
          "following_id": "test",
          "follower_id": "hide"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want to print out only `userid` in followers.

So I add `attributes` option like this.

`{ model: User, as: 'follower', attributes: ['userid']},`

And output is here.

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": {
    "no": 3,
    "userid": "hide",
    "userpw": "$2a$10$oN/.mEuSb8RzRkK.NdyNP.ZbkvcWOSMSsMnxmR.jRWB6wodFTyI02",
    "created_at": "2018-07-19T06:01:17.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-19T06:01:17.000Z",
    "follower": [
      {
        "userid": "test",
        "follow": {
          "created_at": "2018-07-19T06:02:09.000Z",
          "updated_at": "2018-07-19T06:02:09.000Z",
          "following_id": "test",
          "follower_id": "hide"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any solutio to remove `follow` under the `userid`?

I want to only show `userid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include part is not correct. You should include the model you want (User) with the correct as, so to query the user and its followers :

```
User.find({
    where: {
        userid: req.params.id
    },
    include: [
        { 
            model: User, 
            as: 'followers',
            through: {attributes: []}
        }
    ]
})
```

Also, you should change your association definition which read `as: 'follower'` instead of `as: 'followers'`

[EDIT] you may try with options.include[].through.attributes to remove unwanted attributes from the through model. Please keep in mind next time, that you should create separate questions

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. anyway, I have more question and I add it to my post's last section. Can you answer it to me?

Comment: I think you should clean that up in code, if the attributes option doesn’t work, I don’t see any other solution.

Comment: @Hide or try with the options.include[].through.attributes , just updated my answer. I'm not sure this will remove every attributes, but it should clean up pretty well.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Anyway, I want to more information what you mentioned. `(through: {attributes: []})` Is it written on document?

Comment: Yes I had to search in the documentation, it’s only in the detailed options listing from the « reference » section

Comment: I really appreciate it. You save my time :)